# Stress the bandwidth and disk read in linux

Tags: disk, testdisk, bandwidth, testing, stress-testing

I need to trigger HighBandwidth and high disk read for my alert testing purpose. So does anyone knows any Linux command to trigger HighBandwidth(transmitted and received) at 70GB as well as disk read more than 50MB for testing purpose?

Comment: Just to confirm, you would like to *intentionally DDOS* one (or more) of your systems? 

Comment: No, it's for grafana purpose. I have the queries to trigger but dont know how to trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger the highest possible bandwidth by sending `/dev/zero` from one computer to `/dev/null` in a different one directly connected. You may achieve this by using `socat`:

in one computer:

```
socat - TCP-LISTEN:9999 </dev/zero
```

in another one connected to it:

```
socat TCP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9999 - >/dev/null
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the IP of the other machine.

If you want to see which throughput you are having, you may use `pv`, which will print it:

```
socat TCP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9999 - | pv >/dev/null
```

Similarly you can read a very large file and discard it to `/dev/null`:

```
cat /very_large_file | pv >/dev/null
```

to trigger high disk read.

Comment: Hello. Since the OP has not stated which version of Ubuntu they are running my comment may not be correct. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 there is no socat command. A complete answer would say where to get the command and how to install it.

Comment: Try apt install socat ?